# I have 3 highly-related sub-questions to a main question about media licenses - where do I post?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question in this exact form:

---

I was about to clear my cookies in Chrome when I came across this setting under `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` that I've never seen before:

[image: Google Chrome media licenses]

I'm guessing that it's some sort of specialized certificate used by Netflix and other streaming sites to ensure that their content is encrypted before being sent on the wire, and distinct from the normal TLS certificate issued by a CA.

What are media licenses, how are they used by media streaming services like Netflix, and how are they used and stored by Google Chrome?

---

It could belong on:

1. SuperUser.SE - because it has to do with Google Chrome and its settings
2. WebApps.SE - because it has to do with media providers/web apps like Netflix
3. Security.SE - because it's about protecting/encrypting streaming media content

There are 3 highly-related questions:

1. What are media certificates and how are they used by media streaming services such as Netflix? (WebApps.SE)
2. How do media certificates protect streaming media? (Security.SE)
3. How are media certificates used by and stored in Google Chrome? (SuperUser.SE)

Is splitting and posting on individual Stacks the right option, or should I post the entire question on the most-fit Stack? If the latter, which Stack is the best fit?

Answer (score 3):

Your first two "sub"-questions look pretty similar, but to my knowledge would be acceptable on both sites. The [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) site is another good option. The third is really quite independent.

Definitely do not post all three in one question.

You're missing perhaps the most important question I can think of though: does clearing temporary cached browser data really have a permanent impact on netflix.com?

Answer (score 1):

None of the questions would be suitable on Security.SE, so please do not post them there. How media certificates protect streaming media is not on topic there.